# How to hard code credentials AWS SES JS SDK V3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

AWS forced me to upgrade do SDK V3, and now I'm having such a hard time setting up my credentials. They used to be hard-coded like:

```js
AWS.config.update({
  apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
  accessKeyId: "MYKEY",
  secretAccessKey: "MYOTHERKEY",
  region: "us-east-1",
});
```

But now the `AWS` package is deprecated in favor of the modularized `@aws-sdk/client-ses`.

How to hard code my credentials as I used to do in this new version of the SDK?

What I have so far:

```js
import {
  SESClient,
  CloneReceiptRuleSetCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";

const client = new SESClient({
  accessKeyId: "MYKEY",
  secretAccessKey: "MYOTHERKEY",
  region: "us-east-1",
});

const command = new CloneReceiptRuleSetCommand(params);

client.send(command)
```

But it returns me the error "CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers"

P.S.: I know the disadvantages of hard-coding credentials, but this is not a issue for this application in particular. It's a backend Node.js service, and only I need to have access to it.

Comment: Did you read [the API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ses/classes/sesclient.html)? Looks like you _can_ still pass credentials in when you instantiate the client. But why not just set the default env vars?

Comment: @jonrsharpe maybe I'm mistaken, but as far as I understood, the env vars would be attached to my computer, and I don't want that. I want that if I switch computers, the credentials be attached in some file in the GitHub repo, so that I can work normally in the other computer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key and the secret need to be in the `credentials` object of the configuration object.

Also, for `CloneReceiptRuleSetCommand`, you need to provide `OriginalRuleSetName` and `RuleSetName`.

So, it should be like this:

```
import {
  SESClient,
  CloneReceiptRuleSetCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";

const client = new SESClient({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: "MYKEY",
    secretAccessKey: "MYOTHERKEY"
  },
  region: "us-east-1",
});

const params = {
  OriginalRuleSetName: 'RULESET_TO_CLONE', 
  RuleSetName: 'TARGET_RULESET'
}

const command = new CloneReceiptRuleSetCommand(params);

client.send(command)
```

References:

- [Type definition for the SESClient constructor config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ses/interfaces/sesclientconfig.html)
- [Type definition of the `credentials` object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ses/interfaces/awscredentialidentity.html)
- [Constructor definition of the CloneReceiptRuleSetCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ses/classes/clonereceiptrulesetcommand.html#constructor)

Comment: Tried like that too, but got the following error: SESServiceException [ValidationError]: 2 validation errors detected: Value null at 'originalRuleSetName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null; Value null at 'ruleSetName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null

Comment: @PedroRabbi How does your `params` object look like? Can you please add that as well to the question?

Comment: My `params` object was the email object with sender, subject, body etc. I should be calling the `SendEmailCommand` with those parameters, instead of calling `CloneReceiptRuleSetCommand` as in one of the AWS docs I read. It's working now, your question made me see the error. Thanks bro!